# Matching 2 arrays based on the values of some fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have the following list of ingredients in an array called **myBar**. The ingredient is contained in the attribute "name"

```
myBar:  Array [
  bar {
    "category": "spirits",
    "id": "1",
    "ingredientId": "2003",
    "name": "vodka",
  },
  bar {
    "category": "juice",
    "id": "2",
    "ingredientId": "2017",
    "name": "orange juice",
  },
  bar {
    "category": "juice",
    "id": "3",
    "ingredientId": "2020",
    "name": "lemon juice",
  },
  bar {
    "category": "juice",
    "id": "4",
    "ingredientId": "2027",
    "name": "Pineapple Juice",
  },
  bar {
    "category": "juice",
    "id": "5",
    "ingredientId": "2018",
    "name": "apple Juice",
  },
  bar {
    "category": "juice",
    "id": "6",
    "ingredientId": "2025",
    "name": "Lime Juice",
  },
  bar {
    "category": "spirits",
    "id": "7",
    "ingredientId": "2001",
    "name": "gin",
  },
  bar {
    "category": "spirits",
    "id": "8",
    "ingredientId": "2005",
    "name": "whiskey",
  },
  bar {
    "category": "spirits",
    "id": "9",
    "ingredientId": "2002",
    "name": "rum",
  },
]
```

I also have a second array called **cocktailList** containing a list of cocktail recipes. In here the ingredients are contained within the field "ingredients".

```
cocktailList:  Array [
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1101", 
    "ingredients": " gin, lime syrup, lime",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1102", 
    "ingredients": "vodka, orange juice",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1103", 
    "ingredients": "rum, coke",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1104", 
    "ingredients": "sweet vermouth, campari, prosecco",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1105", 
    "ingredients": "Gin, Olive Juice, Olives, Dry vermouth",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1106", 
    "ingredients": " Vodka, Triple Sec, Lime Juice",
},
Object {
    "alcoholic": "true",    
    "drinkId": "1107", 
    "ingredients": " vodka, Raspberry Liqueur, Pineapple Juice",
}
]
```

I'm trying to check what cocktails I can make based on a match of the content of the ingredients.
The idea is to iterate each recipe (in **cocktailList**) and check that ALL ingredients are also part of my list of ingredients in **myBar**.

For example "drinkId": "1102" should return true since I have all ingredients (**vodka** and **orange juice**) in **myBar** while "drinkId": "1101" should return false since I don't have neither lime syrup nor lime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of ingredients names from first array, so that you can quickly search for an ingredient in direct array.

```
// arr1 is your list of ingredients in your bar.
var arrName  = [];
arr1.forEach(element => arrName.push(element.name));

console.log(arrName);
Output:
["vodka", "orange juice", "lemon juice", "Pineapple Juice", "apple Juice", "Lime Juice", "gin", "whiskey", "rum"]
```

Now loop through `cocktailList` and for each ingredient search in `arrName`. If count of matching element is equal to count of ingredients in cocktail then its a match.

```
var finalArr = arr2.filter(function(obj){
    var arrIngredient = obj.ingredients.split(',');
    var intMatch = 0;
    
    arrIngredient.forEach(element => arrName.indexOf(element.trim()) >= 0 ? intMatch++ : '');
    
    return arrIngredient.length == intMatch;
});

console.log(finalArr);
Output:
[
    {
         alcoholic: "true"
         drinkId: "1102"
         ingredients: "vodka, orange juice"
    }
]
```

Comment: many thanks, works well. I just had to add .toLowerCase() to both array outputs before the matching. If I wanted to have just 1 ingredient to be part of the recipe, should I use .some instead of indexOf?